# Checking if an image is present within <ul> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return-value

I am checking on clicking a button that image is present within an `<ul>` tag or not. For that I am using this function :

```
function check_image_exists(){

         $('ul#show_uploaded_images').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).find('img').length) {
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
            });

    }
```

Now if I put this thing within the clicking function it is working...

```
function insert_product(){

$('ul#show_uploaded_images').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).find('img').length) {
                        alert("Image found");
                    }else{
                        alert("Not found");
                    }
            });



}
```

But if I separate the two and try to use only the return value to decide my condition then it is not working. :

```
function check_image_exists(){

         $('ul#show_uploaded_images').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).find('img').length) {
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
            });

    }

function insert_product(){

 var image_exist = check_image_exists();

        if(image_exist == false){


           alert("not found")


        }else{

         do the rest.....

}

}
```

Comment: Why you are using each here $('ul#show_uploaded_images').each,id is comman only one element there you can use directly **$('ul#show_uploaded_images').has("img")**

Comment: what is the console error

Comment: I just found out this piece of code on another stackoverflow answer and implemented it. Is that the problem for not working?

Comment: @Bala thanks for letting me know. But still not working in my condition.

Comment: @Josemon When I try printing `image_exist` in console, it's showing undefined.

Comment: @nick see this working demo http://jsfiddle.net/24427kda/6/

Comment: @nick what is being returned is inside the `each` function, you aren't returning anything from `check_image_exists`

Comment: @Bala This way it is working that I know.. But can you make it work like my last way where there is two function. like I did in the last way? All I need is to determine what the `check_image_exist()` function is returning and use it in the function `insert_product()` for conditions

Comment: @nick Based on asking 2 function http://jsfiddle.net/24427kda/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to return a value in an `each` callback, but that doesn't have any meaning, so the return value just gets swallowed.

There's a much simpler way to do this. Just check whether `.find()` returns any elements:

```
var thereAreImages = $('ul#show_uploaded_images').find('img').length !== 0;
```

Or to package it up in functions:

```
function check_image_exists() {
    return $('ul#show_uploaded_images').find('img').length !== 0;
}

function insert_product() {
    if (check_image_exists()) {
        // do the rest...
    } else {
        console.log('not found');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: based on you asking 2 function ,

```
function insert_product() {
    var image_exist = check_image_exists();
    if (image_exist) {
        alert("here")
    } else {

        alert("not found")
    }

}

function check_image_exists() {
    return $('ul#show_uploaded_images').has("img").length;
}
insert_product();
```

NOTE: You can check direcly `$('ul#show_uploaded_images').has("img").length`

Comment: Thanks I understood this way... However I accepted the previous answer since it came first and was working.. .